# How to return results that have String A with String B, but not any values that have String B without String A

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working in Redshift with a field that tracks the position of an engagement -- the field can contain the following values:

FT, LC, PostLC, OC, Form, CW

and can have any combination of those really. I specifically only want to see ones that are LC touchpoints.

This means they must contain the LC string -- if i do:

'ilike '%LC%' i will get results that dont contain the LC position, but contain the PostLC position. I need to only return the values that contain the LC position with other values.

for example 'FT,LC,PostLC,OC' would be fine, but 'PostLC, OC, CW' would not be acceptable.

How can i translate this into a SQL condition in the where clause?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that you need to include commas and spaces into your thinking so that (for example) `like '%, LC%'` will help differentiate LC from PostLC.

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95f53/2)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (engagements varchar(100))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (engagements)
VALUES
    ('FT, LC, PostLC, OC, Form, CW')
  , ('PostLC, OC, CW')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from table1
where engagements like '%, LC%'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95f53/2/0)**:

```
|                  engagements |
|------------------------------|
| FT, LC, PostLC, OC, Form, CW |
```

However the harder (to accept) answer is you should change your data model so that comma separated string becomes a new table with rows for each new value.

**edit**
Also note that the first item in the list has no preceding comma. So your queries will become a bit more complex:

```
select *
from table1
where engagements like '%, LC%' 
or  engagements like 'LC ,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like`:

```
where ',' || field || ',' like '%,LC,%'
```